# Why is the math code causing transactions to fail

Tags: solidity, transactions, contract-invocation, contract-debugging, safemath

Ok so This is my first time working on solidity contracts and I'm at a loss how to debug this code.
This code fails:

```
 function claimReturns(address claimant) private {
        uint otherTotals = safeSub(lastYearsTotalSupply, accounts[claimant].balance);
        uint newAmount = safeDiv(safeMul(safeMul(accounts[claimant].balance, multiplier), otherTotals), lastYearsTotalSupply);
        mint(newAmount, claimant);
    }
```

while this code succeeds:

```
 function claimReturns(address claimant) private {
        mint(20000000000000000000, claimant);
    }
```

I don't think its a gas issue because the failed transaction is reported that only like 20% of the gas I allocated was used.  But I can't see anything wrong with my math either.
I'm testing on the ropsten network with remixIDE.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what library you're using.

They are usually designed to fail on an overthrow or underflow.

For example:

```
require(total >= arg1);
```

It is probably because `lastYearsTotalSupply == 0` which will cause division to fail. Another possibility is the inputs are so large it is causing multiplication to overthrow.

In case the library has functions like `safeMul(uint a, uint b) ...` you can use a little syntax sugar to attach the methods to the type, `uint`, and write it more readably (the first arg is the variable invoking the method).

```
contract Foo {

  using Math for unit; // has the safeAdd function where the first arg is a uint

  function adder(uint x, uint y) public pure returns(uint sum) {
    sum = x.safeAdd(y);
  }

}
```

You would get something like:

```
newAmount = accounts[claimant].balance
  .safeMul(multiplier)
  .safeMul(otherTotals)
  .safeDiv(lastYearsTotalSupply);
```

Hope it helps